# Questions about ratios

Tags: rational-functions

At a school dance, each boy danced with exactly three girls and each girl danced with exactly two boys.  if 100 boys attended the school dance, how many girls attended?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $(b_1, b_2, \dots b_{100})$ be a set of boys and $(g_1, g_2, \dots g_{n})$ be a set of girls. **IF** $a_1$ dances with $g_1, g_2$ and $g_3$, he can't dance anymore. But $g_1, g_2$ and $g_3$ can dance for **once** more with a guy. Let $g_1, g_2, g_3$ dance with $a_2$. Now you must have new set of girls: $(g_4, g_5, g_6)$ they dance with $(a_3, a_4)$. *Do you see a pattern here?*

Comment: Thanks!  All good!  150 :)